# Should Install Ubuntu MATE if it shows problems while trying it?

Tags: sound, ubuntu-mate, usb-installation

I want to install Ubuntu MATE to a lenovo laptop that is currently running Windows 10.

Yesterday I made a bootable usb with MATE and made the laptop to reboot from it. I thought before installing Ubuntu on my laptop I should try it first without installing just to see if everything works OK.

Everything worked fine (sound, video, wifi, bluetooth etc) but after a few minutes in "try" mode ubuntu froze completely and I had to reboot from power button. I think this was due to my usb stick because it is a bit old and slow.

Since then if I boot again in "try" mode there is no sound from the speakers, but with headphones works fine. Back in windows everything seems to be working perfectly except time. I had to manually go and change time zone to get the correct time(don't think it's a serious problem but i'm newbie with ubuntu so i'm just mentioning it).

*Edit:
Ubuntu freezes every time I try to select the language button on the top right corner and I have to use the laptop's power button to reboot.*

**Q1: Should I install Ubuntu MATE on my laptop if in "try" mode seems to be having problems?**

**Q2: Also, could the bootable usb be corrupted from the first time I rebooted with power button and causing all this?**

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: The USB will be read-only while you try Ubuntu MATE with it, so turning off the computer suddenly shouldn't hurt it. Don't install if it's having issues. [Verify your downloaded ISO](https://ubuntu-mate.org/how-to-verify-downloads/) and redownload if necessary (reverify each time), then try it on a new USB drive if you can because your USB drive might be have been broken to start with. The time issue can be fixed if needed after things work properly otherwise.

Comment: @DavidFoerster hello. Thank you for your comment!  I separated my questions to 2 different ones. I hope that's what you meant. Newbie to stack exchange as well! :)

Comment: I meant that you should rather [open a new question post](/questions/ask) and migrate on of your questions there. It doesn't hurt to make them stand out more visually from each other  though.

Comment: Splitting this up into two separate questions is good. Please also specify WHICH version number of Ubuntu MATE you are working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Q: Should I install Ubuntu MATE on my laptop if in "try" mode seems to be having problems?*

A: I would say **Yes**, but with some comments.

- Problems might be caused by a bad USB pendrive (hardware or software).

  - [Check the iso file with md5sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)
  - [Check the live system from the first menu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13511608#post13511608)
- Minor problems can be solved.
- Please [consider which version 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS ...) to install](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865).
- You can try also some other light-weight flavour of Ubuntu (Lubuntu, Ubuntu Budgie and Xubuntu) before you decide to install, or if your computer is powerful enough, standard Ubuntu and Kubuntu.
- Please consider dual boot with Windows, to install your Ubuntu flavour (MATE or another one) alongside Windows, particularly if this is the first time you use linux. Otherwise, if you know linux already, you need not keep Windows.
- And in any case, please **backup** everything, that you cannot afford to lose before you start installing. Installing an operating system is potentially risky, so it is better to be safe than sorry. You can backup only some personal files, but you can also backup the whole Windows (for example with [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org))

---

*Q: Also, could the bootable usb be corrupted from the first time I rebooted with power button and causing all this?*

A: It depends how it was created.

- If it was created with a cloning tool, and the iso file was good, I would say no.
- If it was created with an extracting tool, and particularly if it is a persistent live drive, it is possible.

Comment: It's also possible the ISO file was corrupted or the USB drive is bad.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex, You are right. I will modify the answer to take that into account.

Comment: @sudodus this is not my first time with using linux but I am newbie enough for this to be the first time to try and install on my laptop something different than windows. So I chose MATE for its low requirements nad for the looks of it ;) !

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex and sudodus thank you both for your answer and comments!! The usb drive was created using rufus. I have used it before for installing Windows with the same usb drive with no problem. Also I have just verified the ISO with which I created the bootable usb using md5&sha and seems to be ok. Unfortunately i don't have a second drive available so I tried to recreate the bootable on the same usb. Again there is the same problem. What seems so strange to me is that the first time I tried MATE the sound was working perfectly. What could have changed so suddenly?

Comment: @IncogniBit204, The checksums match and Rufus is a reliable tool. I think your USB drive is correct. I don't know why the sound stopped working from the speakers. Are you sure that it worked the first time? Did you boot with exactly the same hardware connected? For example the head-phones? I guess that Ubuntu MATE uses `pavucontrol`. You can use it to modify the audio settings and try to get sound from the speakers (it will not survive reboot in a live system, but later on in an installed system it will survive).

Comment: @sudodus Yeah the first time the speakers worked like a charm! I remember because I wanted to test specific things on live system to see if i could proceed with the installation. The only hardware I had on my laptop is just a plug'n'play usb mouse, which I tried to start the live system without it but nothing's changed. I only tried the headphones when I saw there was a problem. But I guess that if with the headphones the sound is ok maybe there is something going on with the speakers drivers? Also ubuntu uses pavucontrol or pulseaudio? In google I only find pulseaudio for ubuntu in general.

Comment: Since it's likely not a corrupted installer, I'd say go ahead and install it and you can ask a new Ask Ubuntu question or two if the actual installed version has some issues. Sometimes the installed version can fix problems that the trial has. What you can do is install it alongside Windows, test it out, figure out how to fix problems if there are any, and then (if everything works and you want to get rid of Windows) zap Windows and reinstall MATE from scratch using the whole disk.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I'll probably do something like what you are suggesting. While searching in google I found many reports for this exact problem with sound after installing, but one way or another it is fixed. Thank you very much Chai T. Rex :) !